# Register Javascript to Dynamic Nested Collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM collapsible which is being dynamically created on button click. I want to created nested collapsibles dynamically for which I need to register a javascript like we do for normal html controls by passing "this" which is the control object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrList.length; i++) {
           var arr = arrList[i].split('#');
           var Programme = arr[0];
           var arr2 = arr[1].split('><');
           var revenue = arr2[0];
           var time = arr2[1];

      // Append a new collapsible and store it into a JQuery object                 
      $('#tdDynamic').append('<div id="collapsible_PG' + i + '" 
                                   data-role="collapsible" 
                                   data-collapsed="true" 
                                   data-theme="e" 
                                   data-content-theme="c"'
                                   + ' onclick="onexpand(this);"></div>');

       // Append the list header and store it into a JQuery object
       var collapsible = $('#collapsible_PG' + i);

      collapsible.append('<h3 id="h3Text_PG' + i + '">' 
                           + Programme + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' 
                           + time + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' 
                           + revenue + '</h3>');
//var h3Text = $('#h3Text' + i);
//collapsible.bind('expand', function () { onexpand('#h3Text' + i); });
                            collapsible.collapsible();
    }
```

Is some this like `onclick="onexpand(this);"` possible?

On button click I have tried using

```
collapsible.bind('expand', function () { onexpand(collapsible); });
```

but this just gives the last id of all the dynamically generated collapsibles onclick.
So even when I click the first collapsible, it shows me the last one which was bound. I guess the bind is overwritten with every new collpasible added in the loop which is why I was looking for some thing like onclick='funcName(this)'. I'm new to JQM please point me in the right direction.

I have referred various SO questions, but couldn't find anything that would help me.

[I reffred to this jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/)

Comment: What I can see is a mix of jQuery with native Javascript. Why use something like `onclick=foo` if you're using jQuery and you could just attach the event handler out of the HTML markup?

Comment: Because my collapsibles are dynamic, which will get generated each time I expand it's parent collapsible. On click I want to know which collapsible is the parent to populated subsequent child collapsibles.

Comment: +1 would have accepted your hint as answer, if it weren't a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment was useful and you probably have found the solution based on it, I'm putting it as an answer.

You can attach the `click` event handler out of the block where you generate the `collapsible`. This way all the future items will be covered automatically:

ie:

```
// Select all divs which id starts with...
$("div[id^='collapsible_PG']").on("click", function () {
    // $(this) here will refer to the exactly element clicked
    onexpand($(this));
});

$('#tdDynamic').append('<div id="collapsible_PG' + i + '" 
    data-role="collapsible" 
    data-collapsed="true" 
    data-theme="e" 
    data-content-theme="c"></div>');
```